# Click event not working after page scroll in safari with reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, safari

When I click on the link it will scroll up to the page rather than fire actual onClick event and open another page...

My ReactJs Code:

```
  <a
    href={HELP_URL}
    className={s.supportLink}
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
    onClick={() => handleFAQClick({ onPageStepChange, location })}
  >
    FAQs
  </a>
```

It should open a new page in a new tab as per mentioned link in "href".

Comment: Could you please provide us with the code related to `hanldeFAQClick()`? Have you checked it does not contain something like `event.preventDefault()`? What is the definition of your `HELP_URL` field in your code? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This one is the actual html code:
<a href="https://help.test.com" class="AccountSettings_supportLink__27jZl" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">FAQs</a>
It's not contain event.preventDefault().

Comment: Try to add `event.preventDefault()` to your 'onclick' event (e.g. to your `handleFAQClick()`).

Comment: I already tried with event.preventDefault(). It's not working.

Comment: Do you get any errors (check console log)?

Comment: No..i can't see any kind of errors in the console log

Answer (score 0):

Add `event.preventDefault()` to your javascript code.

Try something like this:

```js
function handleFAQClick() {
  event.preventDefault(); //<-- If you remove this, your link will try to send you to another page by default.

  //Your code...
  //E.g. alert:
  alert("It works!");
}
```

```html
<a href="" className="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" onClick="handleFAQClick()">
  FAQs
</a>
```